# Protecting files with write permission on database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

On the matter of security I have a neat question.

- How would one protect a directory and the files in that directory from hackers?

CASE:

- All files on a website that have a connection/login to a dBase with write permissions are stored in one directory
- All other requests on the dBase are read only. (ie requests for web pages)
- All is written in PHP and jQuery.
- (With that, this Q is pending as well: how do you also protect the
  download of the main .js file?)

The solution for this is - after extensive research - still not clear to me.

I wonder if you out there have any ideas on this.
And I know it will be very useful to read the thoughts of you out there on this :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: everything that have only local access from php and need no world access (internet) just put in a folder out of the web or add .htaccess role `deny from all`

Comment: What does `All files on a website that have a connection/login to a dBase with write permissions are stored in one directory` mean?

Comment: @SLaks: injections, hack, download... the usual things web owners are afraid off.

Comment: I see a solution in Hawili's answer. How would one get access to files other then DOCUMENT_ROOT in php?

Comment: So you are afraid that people will be able to open your php files and get your DB credentials?  I'm confused what you are asking...

Comment: If you prohibit the download of any js file, that file will no longer work for the client.

Comment: in php you can include files from anywhere, not just server web folder, you can simply use full path inside includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could go about this. The first way would be to use an .htaccess file within the directory you don't want anyone to see. Something like the following should work:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

The better approach would be to store the credentials in a separate file on the server outside of your www root.

```
<?php
$dbUsername = 'mywebapp';
$dbPassword = 'jlsdkfj94r493340rfj30f';
?>
```

Then simply include it in your main code

```
<?php
include '/path/to/secure/location/vars.php';
?>
```

This also let's you restrict access to that file a bit more tightly. I don't add my passwords to source control for instance.

The part II of your question regarding general security of sites really depends on how secure you need to be. Javascript files will always need to be client accessible and anything in those files can be pulled out and read without much effort.

my quick web security tips would be:

- sanitize/parameterize any input from the user heading to the database
- remove passwords and sensitive info from public files
- stay up-to-date with security patches for your webserver
- always use a well-established and test cryptography library. Never try to implement this yourself
- salt and hash any passwords that hit your database

Network and computer security is a whole discipline, so if your risk is high, you may want to look for a specialist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect them from reading you could use ioncube to encode them. But with a  safe website you don't need to think about securing your files as nobody exept you has access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches to security of this kind of course. But a simple approach for basic security could be to deny directory listing to the folder and then to create encoded filenames and put these in the dBase.

Comment: if you want security also dont put sensitive things in the js file. Use server-side execution for this purpose...

Comment: an easy way to block directory listing is to include an empty index.html file in said directory.